# www.mydomain.example secure but not mydomain.example?

Tags: apache, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Certification on both www and no-www domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/ssl-certification-on-both-www-and-no-www-domains)

We've got our website running and HTTPS / SSL works just great.

EXCEPT

when users enter `http://www.mydomain.example` and then enter the secure area and get directed to `httpS://www.mydomain.example` it works fine.

But when users enter just `http://mydomain.example` and then enter the secure are and get directed to `httpS://mydomain.example` they get a warning about the certificate being from a website called `www.mydomain.example` while they're trying to enter `mydomain.example` ....

Does our SSL cert not cover both `www.mydomain.example` and `mydomain.example`? Are we suppose to buy TWO certs, on for each?? Surely not?

Any help or pointers to the standard way of doing things like this would be great.

We're using Apache HTTPD to forward requests to Tomcat webapps. Apache is taking care of all the SSL connections.

Comment: A little SEO note: It's wise to only use one of those forms. Redirect example.com to www.example.com, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Make `http://example.com` redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

To answer your remaining questions, no - SSL certificate verification steps covers only the configured name.  It is possible to obtain a certificate that covers more than one name; and is supported in all modern browsers.